# Convert Microsoft.Data.SqlClient connections, commands, parameters etc. to System.Data.SqlClient

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, sqlclient

Last year, Microsoft introduced the new [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/).

Now, if I wanted to write library code that takes for example a `SqlConnection`, how do I approach this so that it works for both `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` and the old `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`? Is there a built-in way, or a third party package, that can bridge the gap between the two SqlClient packages? Or do I have to double my library code, to be able to support both packages?

Comment: I don't see why you need to. Use `DbConnection` etc as a base class, and use maybe Dependency Injection to decide which type to use

Comment: Create two versions of the library, you can use conditional compilation.

Comment: They're unrelated. Do what dapper did and write extension methods that take both and/or switch on the type of an object parameter. Or use the types from System.Data.Common (ie DbCommand) or the interfaces from System.Data (IDbConnection)

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for the hint, I failed to realize they both inherited from the same `DbConnection`. Feel free to turn your comment into an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you need to duplicate any code. The queries remain the same, just some additional features such as Azure Active Directory integration are available.

Use `DbConnection`, `DbCommand` etc as base classes, and maybe use Dependency Injection or a similar technique to decide which type to use.